# bash script for word count a particualar file in a directory then the result is output in a logfile and the logrotate

Tags: bash

bash script to word count a particualar file in a directory then the result is output in a logfile and then entry in the  log file rotate.

this is what I have tried 
something like:

```
 Dir=$1

        filename="${Dir#*.}"

        auditfile="/tmp/claim"


        claims=`wc $filename`  # count the number of users

        if [ -d $Dir ]; then

 find . -type f -exec wc -l {} \; |  awk -F'[;/.]' '{print $1}' | sort -n | uniq -c


 # will need to use awk here to find the correct count.


fi

preclaims="grep $filename $auditfile" # will need to use awk here to find the correct count.

echo $filename:$claims > $auditfile
echo $prevclaims - $claims
```

Will need to determine when logfile rotates, something like

```
if $claims > $prevclaims then $prevclaims = 0
```

Comment: Please format your code more clearly. Use the code formatting (`{}`) button on the toolbar. Also *clearly* state what isn't working (if something isn't working) or what you are having trouble adding (and show any attempts you've made).

Comment: I having issue with this last part of the script if $claims > $prevclaims then $prevclaims = 0

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals#Conditional_Blocks_.28if.2C_test_and_.5B.5B.29